# Flume HDFS sink keeps rolling small files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, twitter4j, cloudera, flume

I'm trying to stream twitter data into hdfs using flume and this: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/

Whatever I try here, it keeps creating files in HDFS that range in size from 1.5kB to 15kB where I would like to see large files (64Mb).
Here is the agent configuration:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = test

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.idleTimeout = 0

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

EDIT: I looked into the log files and found this happening all the time:

> 9:11:27.526 AM    WARN    org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter     Block
>   Under-replication detected. Rotating file. 9:11:37.036 AM     ERROR
>     org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter
>
> Hit max consecutive under-replication rotations (30); will not
>   continue rolling files under this path due to under-replication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the HDFS replication factor. As I am working on a virtual machine with 1 virtual datanode I had to set the replication factor to 1 in order for it to work as expected.

Comment: I am getting the same error, how did you resovled? how did you set the replication factor to 1?

Comment: I found it, it was in path /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml and the property name is dfs.replication, I have set it to 1. It worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Set `dfs.replication` on your cluster to an appropriate value. This can be done via editing `hdfs-site.xml` file (on all machines of cluster). However, this is not enough.

You also need to create `hdfs-site.xml` file on your flume classpath and put the same `dfs.replication` value from your cluster in it. Hadoop libraries look at this file while doing operations on the cluster, else they use default values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```