# flume hdfs rollSize not working in multi channels and multi sinks

Tags: hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to use Flume-ng to grab 128MB of log information and put it into a file in HDFS. But HDFS rolling options not working. Flume-ng send log file per seconds. How can I fix flume.conf file?

```
agent01.sources = avroGenSrc
agent01.channels = memoryChannel hdfsChannel
agent01.sinks = fileSink hadoopSink

# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
agent01.sources.avroGenSrc.type = avro
agent01.sources.avroGenSrc.bind = dev-hadoop03.ncl
agent01.sources.avroGenSrc.port = 3333

# The channel can be defined as follows.
agent01.sources.avroGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel hdfsChannel

# Each sink's type must be defined
agent01.sinks.fileSink.type = file_roll
agent01.sinks.fileSink.sink.directory = /home1/irteam/flume/data
agent01.sinks.fileSink.sink.rollInterval = 3600
agent01.sinks.fileSink.sink.batchSize = 100

#Specify the channel the sink should use
agent01.sinks.fileSink.channel = memoryChannel



agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.type = hdfs
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.path = hdfs://dev-hadoop04.ncl:9000/user/hive/warehouse/raw_logs/year=%Y/month=%m/day=%d
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.filePrefix = AccessLog.%Y-%m-%d.%Hh
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.rollSize = 134217728
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.rollCount = 0

#Specify the channel the sink should use
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.channel = hdfsChannel


# Each channel's type is defined.
agent01.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent01.channels.hdfsChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
agent01.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100000
agent01.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000

agent01.channels.hdfsChannel.capacity = 100000
agent01.channels.hdfsChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. dfs.replication mismatch cause this problem.

In my hadoop conf (`hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml`)

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>
```

I have 2 data nodes so I change it to

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>
```

and I add config in `flume.conf`

```
agent01.sinks.hadoopSink.hdfs.minBlockReplicas = 2
```

thanks for

https://qnalist.com/questions/5015704/hit-max-consecutive-under-replication-rotations-error

and

[Flume HDFS sink keeps rolling small files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145899/flume-hdfs-sink-keeps-rolling-small-files)